# What is the general procedure to come up with different estimator with smaller MSE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, sampling, inference, mse

PDF of a random variable $X$  is,
$$
\begin{equation}
f\left(x|\gamma\right)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\gamma} \exp(-\frac{x}{\gamma}) & x > 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I got the estimator using negative log-likelihood function and equal it with zero:
$$\hat{\gamma}_{\text{MLE}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$

But can I get an estimator with better MSE (i.e smaller MSE) compared to the $\hat{\gamma}_{\text{MLE}}$? And what will be the general procedure to come up with another estimator because the mathematical framework will alway give me the fixed $\hat{\gamma}_{\text{MLE}}$ here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Dave

Comment: (1) Presumably "$\theta$" means "$\gamma$"? (2) Could you elaborate on what you mean by a "fixed" estimate?  Your formula clearly varies with $n$ and the $x_i.$ (3) If you want to minimize the MSE, why are you using the MLE?  It doesn't usually have this property.

Comment: I mean assume the samples are from $\text{Dist}(\mu=\gamma, \sigma^2=\gamma^2)$ follows the PDF mentioned, Then if I derive the MLE estimator for $\gamma$ then it will always $\hat{\gamma}_{\text{MLE}}$ (YES $n$ and $x_i$ are varies) but can I always come up with another estimator which can give better MSE? @whuber

Comment: Please see our posts about [MVUEs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mvue+unbiased+estimator) and [variance-bias tradeoff](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+bias+trade*).